# What are the stats or strengths and weaknesses of Mario, Luigi, and Toad?

Tags: nintendo-switch, new-super-mario-bros-u

In New Super Mario Bros U Deluxe for Nintendo Switch, what are each character's stats, or, what are the differences between Mario, Luigi and Toad? For example, it's often common to Mario games that Luigi can jump higher than Mario but it more 'slippery" (meaning ore difficult to control)

Are there any differences in abilities between Mario, Luigi, and Toad? (I do know Toadette and Nabbit have clear differences with regard to items/powerups)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.imore.com/new-super-mario-bros-u-deluxe-beginners-guide. With this article:

- Mario, Luigi and Toad work basically the same.
- Toadette has a little bit of training wheels (She's slipping less in the Luigi U version)
- Nabbit has super training wheels on, you can't get powerups but no ennemies can touch you.